# How to call the JSON data from an url provided?

Tags: json, url, key

guys. I'm not familiar with API call. In this case, I would like to get the JSON data from an url provided by the client.

For example, the url could be `https://test/test/test/test`
and there are headers:

`- partner_key: r935pokA8-98A1-r7y6-i90b-3940632d2q99`
`- regexkey: .*\.test\.ml.*`

How should I get all the JSON data/strings stored in that url? Can I type in 
`https://test/test/test/test?partner_key=r935pokA8-98A1-r7y6-i90b-3940632d2q99&regexkey: .*\.test\.ml.*` to get the data?

I tried the above method and it didn't seem to work...Since I'm quite newbie on this, not sure if I should write some code to get the data?

Thanks and I'm looking forward to hearing some answers!

Answer (score 1):

Use postmen tool to get the data you can call the url like this, 
and get a JSON data response[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery this way:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: 'https://test/test/test/test',
  success: function(data) {
    // then use data returned JSON content...
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for being slow, but can I ask how am I going to use this script? How could I do to load the data? Thank you!!

Comment: it also sent headers parameter in their request

Comment: @Penny. Not sure to really understand the question in your last comment. In your original question you said "you'd like to get the JSON data", and it's what this code does: the JSON data can be used for whatever you want in the following of the Javascript code. But maybe you want only to _humanly look at_ the JSON data returned by the url? If so, sure my answer is not the solution.

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad. Sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I mean your function is general to load JSON data through ajax. But for getting data in JSON response we also sent headers parameters which was not sending in your function

Comment: @cFeed yes. I want to look at the JSON data/call it from the url. I have the same question as Wasiq. Since the ajax function didn't include the header info, can I still get the JSON data from the url?

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad. I'm quite lost: AFAIK the header params are sent by the (likely PHP, or other) script generating the content at the given url, not by the JS code executed client side. And I'm puzzled also by Penny's comment, where she seem to have the need of _seeing_ both the JSON content and the headers. In this case, a simple way is using Firebug, where in the Console tab you can look at all was returned (headers and content).

Comment: @Penny. Please look at my other comment addressed to Wasiq.